# Integral of $\frac{1}{1+(2x)^2}$

Tags: calculus

In my mind the integral becomes $\arctan(2x)$.

But in the textbook it says that the primitive function of 
$$
\dfrac{1}{1+(2x)^2}
$$
is 
$$
\frac{1}{2}\arctan(2x).
$$ 
Where on earth does that factor ($1/2$) come from? I just can't seem to wrap my head around it..

Comment: Try differentiating $y=\arctan(2x)$. What do you get?

Comment: It's just u-substitution. (the chain rule really). u=2x

Answer (score 3):

By the chain rule, the derivative of $\arctan(2x)$ is$$2\arctan'(2x)=\frac2{1+(2x)^2}.$$So, the factor $\frac12$ is there to compensate for that $2$ on the numerator.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Substituting $$2x=t$$ then $$x=\frac{t}{2}$$ and $$dx=\frac{1}{2}dt$$

Answer (score 1):

When you use substitution $$ y=2x$$. You get $$ dy = 2dx$$ which give you $$ dx = (1/2)dy$$

That is why you have the $1/2$